# Is there a document class or package specifically for drafting United States legal documents?

Tags: packages, document-classes, legal-style

I recently drafted a non-disclosure agreement in TeX using the document class article.  I liked doing this a lot and I intend to continue doing my legal paperwork in TeX.

> Do document classes or packages exist specifically for writing U.S. legal documents?

Of course, I can continue to write them as articles, but if tools have already been created to do this, I'd like to take advantage of them.

Comment: This comes up every so often. The big problem is the bluebook citation style. Closest thing to it is http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/camel/ which is moribund.

Comment: @WillAdams Thanks- I did see the related thread about legal citations.  Is there something I should use which does everything but citations?

Comment: Check in http://www.ctan.org/topic/legal if any of those packages, mostly for German lawyers, could be useful your you (directly or maybe as prototypes of your own macros).

Comment: Can you give any pointers on how a legal document looks like? How much effort do you have to do to modify standard `article`. If it is a lot, you could share your mods, robustify them a bit and place it on CTAN. After that, you can place an answer below saying »Yes, there is«. ;-)

Comment: If you enjoy making and using these documents, be sure to get involved with http://www.morninj.com/ ; a project for just this purpose. It looks like they're just getting started, and could use some of your enthusiasm and expertise.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement your link is dead;  does the project exist somewhere else?

Comment: @Una http://www.mornin.org/ I think he's the one who owned morninj.com. Maybe this is the best way to get started? https://groups.google.com/g/latex-for-lawyers?pli=1

Answer (score 5):

There is a package for blue book style written by Chrisopher DeCoro:

[LawTeX](http://sourceforge.net/p/lawtex/wiki/Home/)

Comment: Khm, how would I add this to LyX?

Comment: @MikhailT. LyX does not really use Latex packages like this.  Its encoded differently, yes it can use some Latex code but its not really compatible.